# How to make navbar logo's anchor tag anchor "home"?

Tags: html, css

The title basically says it all.

I have a navbar with a logo and I'm trying to get it so when clicked the page redirects "home" and scrolls back to the top of the page. I'm relatively new to html and CSS but understand how anchoring works, my other navbar anchor links are working correctly I just can't seem to figure the logo out.

Thanks in advance!

```css
/* 
=================
    Navbar
=================
*/

#home {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #fffffff6;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 64px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.links {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.links img {
  max-width: 7rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: auto;
  /* This pushes the logo to the left side of the page */
}

.links li {
  padding: 15px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.links li.items {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 25px;
  text-align: center;
  order: 3;
}

/* Navbar Under Bar */

.links li.items .nav-words:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  bottom: 5px;
  height: 1.5px;
  width: 100%;
  background: var(--c-primary2);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.links li.items .nav-words:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: 8px;
}

.links li a {
  font-weight: 400;
  color: var(--h-text);
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: .05rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .4s;
}

.links button {
  width: 7.6rem;
  height: 2.4rem;
  background: var(--main-gradient);
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  border-radius: 35px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.links button a {
  color: var(--white);
}

.links button:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 12px 10px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
}

.links li .nav-words:hover {
  color: var(--c-primary2);
}

.links li.ham-btn {
  display: none;
}

.links li.ham-btn.hide i:before {
  content: '\f00d';
}
```

```html
<!-- Navbar -->
<section id="home">
  <header class="menu">
    <ul class="links">
      <!-- Logo -->
      <a href="#home"><img class="logo" src="img/central-gardens-logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
      <!-- Words -->
      <li class="items"><a class="nav-words" href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a class="nav-words" href="#services">Services</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a class="nav-words" href="#amenities">Amenities</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a class="nav-words" href="#career">Careers</a></li>
      <li class="items"><a class="nav-words" href="faq.html" target="_blank">FAQ</a></li>
      <!-- Button -->
      <li class="items">
        <button>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </button>
      </li>
      <!-- Hamburger Button -->
      <li class="ham-btn">
        <a class="nav-words" href="#">
          <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding just a '#' as the link should take you to the top of the page, without needing to add the #home

```
<!-- Logo -->
  <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="img/central-gardens-logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
```